# Which project templates I can use to create a winform dll library?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Which project templates in visual studio are appropriate for creating a Winform dll libaray. 
I want to use it for creating a plug-in interface window. I am looking for an alternative for `WPF User Control Library` in Wiforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a project using the project template `Class Library`

[image]

If you are looking to use `WinForm` classes in your library you are going to have to add the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` as this is not included by default in a `Class Library` project (they are generally used for utility functionality that doesn't require GUI elements) Not to say including GUI elements in a library is wrong, just uncommon, so they don't bother including it by default to cut down on dependencies.

To add `System.Windows.Forms`:

> Solution Explorer -> Right Click References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Framework

Then scroll until you find `System.Windows.Forms`, check it and click OK. You can now use `WinForm` objects in your library.

If you find yourself needing to test library GUI elements `Windows Forms Control Library` template project would probably be a better option

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Creating a **Windows Forms Control Library** is more suitable.

> A project for creating controls to use in Windows Forms Applications

This way it adds windows forms related assemblies to the project and you don't need to add them yourself. It has these references additional to a Class Library project:

- `System.Drawing`
- `System.Windows.Forms`

If you open Add New Project dialog, you can find it in this path:

- `Visual C# > Windows Desktop > Windows Forms Control Library`
- `Visual Basic > Windows Desktop > Windows Forms Control Library`

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar template for Winforms called "Windows Forms Control Library". That's what you're looking for.

Btw you can just use "Class Library" template and add the Windows.Forms library references manually.

Only difference is that you can't run a class library project whereas you can run "Windows Forms Control Library" project where it displays UI to test your user controls.